# Which variables are available inside an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

There's a little something about scope I just keep getting confused about:

```
this.init = function(){
  var t = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    // why is t still available here?
    t.initgame();
    // but not this?
    this.initgame();
  }, 500);
}

this.initgame = function() {
  // yada yada
}
```

I get that inside an anonymous function, scope is different that outside of it.
But why, in the above example, is the variable "t" available inside the timeout function, while "this" is not working?

Comment: `this` is defined nowhere, to begin with.

Comment: @LutzHorn I suppose the code we see is embedded in a place where `this` is defined in a useful way.

Comment: `this` is available, as always, it's just that its meaning has changed.

Comment: `this` is dynamically scoped, not lexically scoped like everything else. If you need the `this` from `this.init`, store it in another variable inside that function, as you're doing with `t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `setTimeout` is called with `window` as scope.

Using a dedicated variable to store `this` (`t`) is a perfectly valid and usual solution.

On modern browsers, [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is sometimes convenient :

```
setTimeout((function(){
    // use this
}).bind(this), 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

When the anonymous function runs, it is no longer running as a member function of `init`, but rather a top-level function of `window`. As a result, `this.initgame()` has no meaning.

For example, running `console.log(this)` inside the timeout function returns as follows:

```
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external:...
```

When you use `var t = this`, you assign reference to the current object, which works.